# Is it possible to stream boost::multiprecision::cpp_int to a lowercase hex string without using std::transform?

Tags: c++, boost

Streaming from `uint256_t` to `std::stringstream` always gives an uppercase hex string.

Adding `std::nouppercase` doesn't seem to help.

What I do now is:

```cpp
std::stringstream stream;
stream << std::hex << uint256;
std::string hex = stream.str();
std::transform(hex.begin(), hex.end(), hex.begin(), [](unsigned char c) { 
    return std::tolower(c); 
});
```

While this gives the desired result, I'm wondering if there is a way to do this without using `std::transform` and `std::tolower`

Comment: Well, if `boost::multiprecision` ignores `std::ios_base::uppercase` flag, then I think you'll indeed have to manually fix up its imperfection. BTW, it also ignores `std::ios_base::floatfield`, so you can't e.g. get `hexfloat` to work with `boost::multiprecision::float128`.

Comment: @Ruslan: These issues were fixed in https://github.com/boostorg/multiprecision/pull/130 and https://github.com/boostorg/multiprecision/pull/122

Comment: @Antouhou: What version of Boost are you using?

Comment: @user14717 I'm using the latest one, 1.70.0

Comment: @user14717 sorry for the confusion, it appears to be 1.63.0. I'm updating now, let's see if it's actually a bug that has been resolved already

Comment: @user14717 I've updated the lib to 1.70.0, the result is the same as above.
I guess it's a bug then.